# Disable aloha completely for inline editing

Tags: neoscms

I would like to use the inline editing feature for a `title` attribute of a custom document node. But the problem is aloha adds `p` and `br` tags when you hit enter in the content canvas but the `title` attribute shouldn't contains any markup or newline chars:

```
aloha:
  placeholder: 'Enter title here'
  autoparagraph: FALSE
    'format': []
    'table': []
    'link': []
    'list': []
    'alignment': []
    'formatlesspaste':
      'button': FALSE
      'formatlessPasteOption': FALSE
```

The part in the template I use for is this: `<h1>{neos:contentElement.editable(property: 'title', node: node)}</h1>`

Is this a feature, a bug or did I miss something? If this is a feature it would mean you can use the inline editing feature only for child nodes and properties with markup right?

Comment: I see, and agree that should be possible. But I think you cannot tell aloha to not allow linebreaks for now. I will check if I find something... But we are working on an upgrade for the editor that hopefully allows for much more configuration.

Comment: That sounds great! Could you post a link to the JIRA issue here?